# google login that doesn't provide callback

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I've implement a simple page that contain a simple google login button, like this:

```
 <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com">
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
 <script>
     function onSignInFailure() {
         alert('no work!');
     }

     function onSignIn(googleUser) {
         alert('it work!');
     }
 </script>

 <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-onfailure="onSignInFailure" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

But when i click on the button, i choose my google account, but nothing happen...
no "alert" is triggered

Comment: anything in the developer tools console?

Comment: Is your html page hosted ? or you are running it locally ?

Comment: @Ruby in your on onSignInFailure() function alert message must be alert('doesn\'t work!');...use escape character for special character...

Comment: @AshrafBashir i'm running it on localhost ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in `onSignInFailure` , it should be:

```
 function onSignInFailure() {
     alert("doesn't work!"); 
 }
```

Comment: yeah it's a mistake in the code, but replaceing it removing the ' it also doesn't works,

(Is a mistake because i translate the alert string in english from italian. in italian string doesn't exist any quotes)